# Search not working on Sharepoint2019 public facing site

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, public-website, cors

I have SharePoint 2019 on premise communication site which manages the public facing site. My search is working on on-premise site but it shows the error message which says

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'On premise site' from origin 'public facing site' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I assume that I need to put the  rules and add allow content origin policy in the web.config file inside the <system.webServer>. What and how should I add the allow customHeaders? The existing customHeaders

```
<add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
<add name="X-MS-InvokeApp" value="1; RequireReadOnly" />
```

Should I delete it?
I tried adding the following but does not work for me.

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>            
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />                
                <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(http(s)?://((.+\.)?domain1\.com|(.+\.)?domain2\.com|(.+\.)?domain3\.com))" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
                </rule>           
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: did you try to disable CORS on your browser ?

Comment: Nope, I managed to tackle this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your SharePoint Communication site is either trying to send multiple **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** headers, or one **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header with multiple values. I believe none is allowed.

So the idea is you need to fix your SPConfig so that it only

- sends this header **once**
- specifies a **single** value

Go to SP Admin Center → App Management → Manage Services on Server :
Stop the **Request Management Service**

Comment: I managed to tackle this. Thanks